# Creating matrix with for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, matrix, range

I have a list with 4 elements. Each element is a correct score that I am pulling from a form. For example:

```
scoreFixed_1 = 1
scoreFixed_2 = 2
scoreFixed_3 = 3
scoreFixed_4 = 4

scoreFixed = [scoreFixed_1, scoreFixed_2, scoreFixed_3, scoreFixed_4]
```

Then, I need to add:

```
scoreFixed_1 to fixture[0][0]
scoreFixed_2 to fixture[0][1]
scoreFixed_3 to fixture[1][0]
scoreFixed_4 to fixture[1][1]
```

Hence, I need to create a triple for loop that outputs the following sequence so I can index to achieve the result above:

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 1 0
3 1 1
```

I have tried to use this to create this matrix, however I am only able to get the first column correct. Can anyone help?

```
for x in range(1):
    for y in range(1):
        for z in range(4):
            print(z, x, y)
```

which outputs:

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
```

Comment: There must be some logic behind this matrix that can be translated into a loop. Could you please add more information about how this matrix is formed?

Comment: are there any rules/conditions for what numbers go where?

Comment: As long as its in the given order that is written in the first code snippet, then it works for me

Comment: But how are those numbers generated? Since there' not ascending, a regular loop won't work. There must be some kinda logic behind it.

Comment: At the moment, there is no logic behind it. I simply need this to index in the correct order for another program. The first list has 4 elements, the second list has 2 elements and so does the third list.

Comment: Then create a hardcoded array with these values.

Comment: I will update with the relevant logic to help you understand.

Comment: See my updated answer to correspond with your updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic does not generate the table, you want something like:

```
rownum = 0
for x in range(2):
    for y in range(2):
        print (rownum, x, y)
        rownum += 1
```

(Edit:  The question has been changed, to accomplish the new desire, you want something like this:)

```
scoreIndex = 0
for x in range(2):
    for y in range(2):
        fixture[x][y] += scoreFixed[scoreIndex]
        scoreIndex += 1
```

Comment: I think you forgot to increment `scoreIndex`

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey  I sure did!  Thanks...  (Edited to correct)

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, it seems like we can split the 'sequence' into:

1. First column, regular ascending variable ( n += 1)
2. Second and third column, binary counter (00, 01, 10, 11)

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 1 0
3 1 1

  ^ ^------- These seem like a binary counter 
                (00, 01, 10, 11)

^------ A regular ascending variable
                ( n += 1 )
```

Using that 'logic' we can create a code that looks like

```py
import itertools 

scoreFixed = 0
for i in itertools.product([0,1],repeat=2): 
    print(scoreFixed, ' '.join(map(str,i)))
    scoreFixed += 1
```

And wil output:

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 1 0
3 1 1
```

As you can test [in this online demo](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEAXv@Yp3a4KhtHoTcvUnxENpI67Y7LJZQb8@ipc652FG3nbjcmiNVmE1kGU15keFc3VmzSd65QUJg7uygkBlc3pRXp6z@fMQx0vULHmytA9HOHwRpWJ@q0R06Po7U/HrJL6aRgoh/Ny/1y5hbO0D)

Answer (score -1):

```
for x in range(4):
    z = int(bin(x)[-1])
    y = bin(x)[-2]
    y = int(y) if y.isdigit() else 0
    print(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Logic is simple. After the number, the next columns represent its binary values.